# How to use Column.isin with list?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

```
val items = List("a", "b", "c")

sqlContext.sql("select c1 from table")
          .filter($"c1".isin(items))
          .collect
          .foreach(println)
```

The code above throws the following exception.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Unsupported literal type class scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon List(a, b, c) 
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Literal$.apply(literals.scala:49)
at org.apache.spark.sql.functions$.lit(functions.scala:89)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Column$$anonfun$isin$1.apply(Column.scala:642)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Column$$anonfun$isin$1.apply(Column.scala:642)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:245)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:245)
at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
at scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray.foreach(WrappedArray.scala:35)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:245)
at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:104)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Column.isin(Column.scala:642)
```

Below is my attempt to fix it. It compiles and runs but doesn't return any match. Not sure why.

```
val items = List("a", "b", "c").mkString("\"","\",\"","\"")

sqlContext.sql("select c1 from table")
          .filter($"c1".isin(items))
          .collect
          .foreach(println)
```

Answer (score 156, accepted):

According to documentation, `isin` takes a vararg, not a list. List is actually a confusing name here. You can try converting your List to vararg like this:

```
val items = List("a", "b", "c")

sqlContext.sql("select c1 from table")
          .filter($"c1".isin(items:_*))
          .collect
          .foreach(println)
```

Your variant with mkString compiles, because one single String is also a vararg (with number of arguments equal to 1), but it is proably not what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 19):

It worked like this in Java Api (Java 8)

```
.isin(sampleListName.stream().toArray(String[]::new))));
```

sampleListName is a List

Answer (score 17):

Spark has now (since 2.4.0) a method called [`isInCollection`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Column@isInCollection(values:Iterable[_]):org.apache.spark.sql.Column), which is just what you are looking for, instead of `isIn`.

(shouldn't they unify the methods?)

Comment: Be aware this method is implemented via: `def isInCollection(values: scala.collection.Iterable[_]): Column = isin(values.toSeq: _*)` (cf: [definition](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Column.scala#L813) ). I don't really know why the API has two different names for similar behaviours.

Comment: That makes me even more confused. I don't really understand. I'd have expected an overloaded method to handle both types of inputs, just like many others in the API. Thank you for the info!

Comment: This [PR](https://github.com/apache/spark/commit/900bc1f7dc5a7c013b473fceab1c4052ade74a2f) introduces the method without explanation :/

Comment: @BlueSheepToken The discussion is on [this](https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/21416) PR. The reason it's not overloaded is that `isin` is defined to take `Any*`, and `Iterable[_]` can be an `Any*`  leading to a conflict.

Comment: I don't know how do you folks find this kind of stuff, but my random tangent question was fully answered 20 months after I let it out to the world. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

As Tomalak has mentioned it :

```
isin(java.lang.Object... list)
A boolean expression that is evaluated to true if the value 
of this expression is contained by the evaluated values of the arguments.
```

Therefore, you just could fix this making the following change :

```
val items = List("a", "b", "c").map(c => s""""$c"""")
```

Comment: Why the map? My is that `.filter($"c1".isin(List("a", "b", "c")))` would work.

Comment: Considering your code `List("a", "b", "c").mkString("\"","\",\"","\"")`, I assumed that you wanted to surround each item by double quotes. The map does the same thing.

Answer (score -1):

Even easier:

```
sqlContext.sql("select c1 from table")
          .filter($"c1".isin("a", "b", "c"))
          .collect
          .foreach(println)
```

Unless you have a lot of list values, which isn't the case usually.