# Spark SQL DF - How to pass multiple values dynamically for `isin` method of `Column`

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to filter the Spark SQL DataFrame with where condition.

**For example:** [ working one]

```
df.where(col("pType").isin("type1","type2"))
```

What I am trying is, instead of hard coding the `pType` values, I  am trying to build it dynamically. So i build a List(String) with all the `pType` values.

For example, if I have `List("type1","type2")`, how can I use this list to `isin` method?

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32551919/spark-filter-isin-doesnt-work-as-expected

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Scala's syntax for converting a collection into a "repeated parameter" (AKA "varargs" in Java-speak, as well as other languages), See section 4.6.2 in the [Scala Language Specification](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf):

```
val list = List("type1","type2")
df.where(col("pType").isin(list: _*))
```