# Spark split a file into multiple folders based on a field

Tags: scala, apache-spark, amazon-s3, split, pyspark

I am trying to split a set of S3 files like below based on a column into individual column based folders. I am not sure of the problem with my code below.

```
column 1, column 2
20130401, value1
20130402, value2
20130403, value3

val newDataDF = sqlContext.read.parquet("s3://xxxxxxx-bucket/basefolder/")
    newDataDF.cache()
    val uniq_days = newDataDF.select(newDataDF("column1")).distinct.show()
    uniq_days.cache()
    uniq_days.foreach(x => {newDataDF.filter(newDataDF("column1") === x).write.save(s"s3://xxxxxx-bucket/partitionedfolder/$x/")})
```

Can you please help? Even a pyspark version is ok.
I am looking for following structure.

```
s3://xxxxxx-bucket/partitionedfolder/20130401/part-***

    column 1, column 2
    20130401, value 1
s3://xxxxxx-bucket/partitionedfolder/20130402/part-***

    column 1, column 2
    20130402, value 1
s3://xxxxxx-bucket/partitionedfolder/20130403/part-***

    column 1, column 2
    20130403, value 1
```

Here is the error

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 22 in stage 82.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 22.3 in stage 82.0 (TID 2753

Driver stacktrace:
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1454)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

**Update with current solution:**

```
val newDataDF = sqlContext.read.parquet("s3://xxxxxx-bucket/basefolder/")
newDataDF.cache()
val uniq_days = newDataDF.select(newDataDF("column1")).distinct.rdd.map(_.getString(0)).collect().toList
uniq_days.foreach(x => {newDataDF.filter(newDataDF("column1") === x).write.save(s"s3://xxxxxx-bucket/partitionedfolder/$x/")})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you missed "s" in the save. :)

http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/string-interpolation.html#the-s-string-interpolator

Change:

```
write.save("s3://xxxxxx-bucket/partitionedfolder/$x/")})
```

To:

```
write.save(s"s3://xxxxxx-bucket/partitionedfolder/$x/")})
```

There are more issues, show never returns any value.

Change:

```
val uniq_days = newDataDF.select(newDataDF("mevent_day")).distinct.show()
uniq_days.cache()
```

To:

```
val uniq_days = newDataDF.select(newDataDF("mevent_day")).distinct.rdd.map(_.getString(0)).collect().toList
```

Comment: I don't think so.. I added it now, still same error.

Comment: Thanks. I made it val uniq_days = newDataDF.select(newDataDF("mevent_day")).distinct.collect().toList
uniq_days.foreach(x => {newDataDF.filter(newDataDF("mevent_day") === x).write.save(s"s3://xxxxxxxx-bucket/partitionedfolder/$x/")})     Error is java.lang.RuntimeException: Unsupported literal type class org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericRowWithSchema [2013-04-02]

Comment: I am guessing this could be a reason - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32551919/spark-filter-isin-doesnt-work-as-expected

Comment: uniq_days - gives me res78: List[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = List([2016-08-17], [2014-12-13], [2014-05-27], ..........

Comment: @androboy: my bad , edited. use val uniq_days = newDataDF.select(newDataDF("mevent_day")).distinct.rdd.map(_.getString(0)).collect().toList

Comment: Thanks! That works. I am wondering if it will write only one row per part-* file in the partitionedfolder..