# Filter via a set in spark sql

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe and I'd like to use a filter for a set of values.

I know outside of spark sql I can use something like this.

```
val SetofUsers = Set("A", "B", "C", "D")
val mydfFiltered = mydf.filter($"user_id" === Some("SetofUsers"))
```

I am getting an error. I looked at the [docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrame.html#filter(org.apache.spark.sql.Column)) and didn't find an answer. How do I filter for a set of values?

Comment: Use isin  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32551919/how-to-use-column-isin-with-list.     Possible duplicate

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use Column.isin with list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32551919/how-to-use-column-isin-with-list)