# Unsupported literal type class scala.collection.immutable.HashSet$HashTrieSet

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe with a list of IDs. I would like to filter it down to just a set of IDs and I used .filter() to do it.

I'm running into this error.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unsupported literal type class scala.collection.immutable.HashSet$HashTrieSet
```

My code is pretty simple.

```
val setofID = Set("112", "113", "114", "121", "118", "120")

val my_dfFiltered = my_df.filter($"id".isin(setofID)).persist
```

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32560177/2639647. `.isin()` takes a variable list of params, not a single iterable. `.isin(setofID:_*)` might work.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`Set` is not working with `isin`, use a `Seq` and use varags like

```
val setofID = Set("112", "113", "114", "121", "118", "120").toSeq

val my_dfFiltered = my_df.filter($"id".isin(setofID:_*)).persist
```

or using `isInCollection` (since Spark 2.4) which accepts `Iterable`, this should work directly with `Set`

```
val my_dfFiltered = my_df.filter($"id".isInCollection(setofID)).persist
```