# How to pass column values in where condition

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am failing to achieve simple SQL query in Spark.

I would like to write the below query in Scala Spark:

```
select * from emp where emp_id in (select distinct manager_id from emp ;
```

Below is what I tried:

```
empdf.where(col("emp_id").isin(empdf.select("manager_id").collect().map(_(0)).toList)).show()
```

I got the below error:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unsupported literal type class scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon List(null, 68319, 68319, 68319, 65646, 65646, 69062, 66928, 66928, 66928, 66928, 67858, 66928, 67832)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better to do a semi join to avoid collecting as list:

```
empdf.alias("t1").join(empdf.alias("t2"), expr("t1.emp_id = t2.manager_id"), "left_semi")
```

If you want to use `isin`, you can expand the List using `: _*` (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32551919/how-to-use-column-isin-with-list)):

```
empdf.where(col("emp_id").isin(empdf.select("manager_id").collect().map(_(0)).toList: _*)).show()
```

Or use `isInCollection`:

```
empdf.where(col("emp_id").isInCollection(empdf.select("manager_id").collect().map(_(0)).toList)).show()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also write as a SQL,

empdf.createorreplaceview("emp")

spark.sql("select * from emp where emp_id in (select distinct manager_id from emp ")